# Find String Between Two Substrings in Python When There is A Space After First Substring

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, string-search

While there are several posts on StackOverflow that are similar to this, none of them involve a situation when the target string is one space after one of the substrings.

I have the following string (example_string):
`<insert_randomletters>[?] I want this string.Reduced<insert_randomletters>`

I want to extract "I want this string." from the string above. The randomletters will always change, however the quote "I want this string." will always be between `[?]` (with a space after the last square bracket) and Reduced.

Right now, I can do the following to extract "I want this string".

```
target_quote_object = re.search('[?](.*?)Reduced', example_string)
target_quote_text = target_quote_object.group(1)
print(target_quote_text[2:])
```

This eliminates the `]` and  that always appear at the start of my extracted string, thus only printing "I want this string." However, this solution seems ugly, and I'd rather make `re.search()` return the current target string without any modification. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to escape `[` and `?`, and add `\s*` after `]`, `'\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced'`

Comment: I ended up using `re.search('] (.*?)Reduced', example_string)`. Would  my solution work too, or is yours more optimal?

Comment: If you do not care if there is `[?` before `]`, it will.

Comment: I would also advise to check if there is a match before accessing `.group(1)` to avoid errors if no match is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `'[?](.*?)Reduced'` pattern matches a literal `?`, then captures any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible up to the first `Reduced` substring. That `[?]` is a *character class* formed with unescaped brackets, and the `?` inside a character class is a literal `?` char. That is why your Group 1 contains the `]` and a space.

To make your regex match `[?]` you need to escape `[` and `?` and they will be matched as literal chars. Besides, you need to add a space after `]` to actually make sure it does not land into Group 1.  A better idea is to use `\s*` (0 or more whitespaces) or `\s+` (1 or more occurrences).

Use

```
re.search(r'\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced', example_string)
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4mA7cF/1).

```
import re
rx = r"\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced"
s = "<insert_randomletters>[?] I want this string.Reduced<insert_randomletters>"
m = re.search(r'\[\?]\s*(.*?)Reduced', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
# => I want this string.
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/BZW70568).

Comment: Question - will this capture the target string if there is only one whitespace after the first substring?

Comment: Yes, since the `\s*` will match zero or more whitespace characters.Check out the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re-syntax) if needed.

Comment: @Roymunson If there is only one literal space, you may use a space. But if you are not sure, you may use any of the hints I added to the answer. BTW, `" +"` matches 1+ spaces, `" *"` matches 0 or more spaces. `\s+` will match 1+ whitespace chars, `\s*` will match 0+.

Answer (score 2):

Regex *may* not be necessary for this, provided your string is in a consistent format:

```
mystr = '<insert_randomletters>[?] I want this string.Reduced<insert_randomletters>'

res = mystr.split('Reduced')[0].split('] ')[1]

# 'I want this string.'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be:

```
target_quote_object = re.search('] (.*?)Reduced', example_string)
target_quote_text = target_quote_object.group(1)
print(target_quote_text)
```

However, Wiktor's solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

You [co]/[sho]uld use Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\[\?\])` :

[image]

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=\[\?\])(\s\w.+?)Reduced'

string_data='<insert_randomletters>[?] I want this string.Reduced<insert_randomletters>'

print(re.findall(pattern,string_data)[0].strip())
```

output:

```
I want this string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer, this might not be necessary. Or just *too long-winded* for Python.
This method uses one of the common string methods `find`.

- `str.find(sub,start,end)` will return the index of the first occurrence of `sub` in the substring `str[start:end]` or returns **-1** if none found.
- In each iteration, the index of `[?]` is retrieved following with index of `Reduced`. Resulting substring is printed.
- Every time this `[?]...Reduced` pattern is returned, the index is updated to the rest of the string. The search is continued from that index.

#### Code

```
s = ' [?] Nice to meet you.Reduced  efweww  [?] Who are you? Reduced<insert_randomletters>[?] I want this 
string.Reduced<insert_randomletters>'


idx = s.find('[?]')
while idx is not -1:
    start = idx
    end = s.find('Reduced',idx)
    print(s[start+3:end].strip())
    idx = s.find('[?]',end)
```

#### Output

```
$ python splmat.py
Nice to meet you.
Who are you?
I want this string.
```